# Color/image to alpha in Blender

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency, color

I want Blender to compare two images and subtract the one image from the other and create an alpha. So far, it turns it white... but I need it to be alpha. I can't just turn white into alpha as there are some times where I want white to be a color left behind on the final image.

Comment: There is a `Combine RGBA` and a `Set Alpha` nodes that will add the alpha channel to the image data. Also are you rendering with transparency or is the white coming from the background colour behind the transparency? Are you saving to PNG to keep alpha or jpeg that will fill in the transparency?

Answer (score 3):

Using the compositor, you can use an Alpha Over node with the top socket set to 0 alpha and plug your main image into the bottom socket. This puts the 0 alpha under the image, and then using the image with the white in it as a mix factor for the alpha over node. To get the result I think you wanted, I inverted the color of the image used as a mask. Notice that since the image I used had a slight gradient of white in it, the black was not pure and so the image left has a slight transparency to it.[image: erase to tranparent]
I also wanted to point out I saved the image result from the 'Viewer' output in the UV Image Editor, and then brought it back in as an image node to confirm that it had a definite alpha. Might need some cleanup with a dilate/erode node, but this gets you there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this in the Compositor, you need to make sure these are enabled on your Subtract node and the Composite node:
[image]